# Unable to clone Git repositories from git clone go.googlesource.com

Tags: linux, git, go

I would like to learn Go language so I wanted to start with tooling installation first. However, I am not able to install golang tools with neither `go get -u golang.org/x/tools` nor `git clone https://go.googlesource.com/tools`. Both of them results into Connection timeout error, the whole message is

```
⇒  go get -u golang.org/x/tools -v
# cd .; git clone https://go.googlesource.com/tools /home/pmensik/go/src/golang.org/x/tools
Cloning into '/home/pmensik/go/src/golang.org/x/tools'...
fatal: unable to connect to go.googlesource.com:
go.googlesource.com[0: 2a00:1450:400c:c0a::52]: errno=Connection timed out
go.googlesource.com[1: 173.194.76.82]: errno=Connection timed out

package golang.org/x/tools: exit status 128
package -v: unrecognized import path "-v" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

Basically the same is for `git clone`.

I also tried to authenticate via `.gitcookie` file generated on go.googlesource.com but it didn't help as well. I can clone any other repositories and I don't experience any other network problem.

My platform is elementaryOS Loki based on Ubuntu 16.02, I am not using VPN or any proxies.  `go env` says the following

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/pmensik/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/pmensik/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build729564191=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

So what could be wrong?

Comment: As for "import path does not begin with hostname", try `go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, outcome is the same https://pastebin.com/U2qaww7n

Comment: Did you add your `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT` to your PATH environment variable from your .profile file? If so, try `$ source ~/.profile`

Comment: I did (just not `$GOPATH` because it defaults to `/usr/local/go` where my go is installed). And I also did refresh and some reboot meanwhile

Comment: Can you view https://go.googlesource.com/ in a web browser? If not, you might have a network issue.

Comment: Yes, I can browse it and ping it as well

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with downloading all the stuff all need in a virtual machine. I am still not sure why it doesn't work on my host machine.